# Setting null value for my objects

Tags: javascript

```
var JsonClient = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

// API Url to call
var url = "";

JsonClient.open("POST", url, true);

JsonClient.onload = function () {
    // after processing the response
    json = null;
}
JsonClient.onerror = function (e) {
    actAllergyInd.hide();
    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
        title: 'Error',
        message: JsonClient.statusText,
        buttonNames: ['Ok']
    }).show();
};
}

//setting Request Header
JsonClient.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
JsonClient.send(data);
JsonClient = null;
```

I want to set my JsonClient object to `null` as well as the Json `response` which i am getting to null. **Am i doing it in the right way?**

Comment: Why do you care? JavaScript is memory-managed, you do not have to "free" stuff after you use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `delete` operator:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

```
delete JsonClient;
```

Comment: `delete` is not a function, it is an operator.

Comment: @Tomalak Thank you, I edited my answer. I did read it was an operator but yet I still put it as an function, silly me...